# How to call api correct with Feign?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have application which calling TMDB api. For api call i use Feign interface:

```
@FeignClient(name = "TMDb-movie", url = "${TMDB_URL}", path = "/movie")
public interface TmdbMovieRMI {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> findById(@PathVariable Integer id,
                                    @RequestParam("api_key") String apiKey);
}
```

But when i do the request i have this error: `feign.codec.DecodeException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}` How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using webmvc (for example because you are using webflux or no web spring boot starter at all) feign clients won't work out of the box.

You have to define the encoder and decoder manually. Insert this in a `@Configuration` class or in your `@SpringBootApplication` class:

```java
@Bean
public Decoder decoder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new JacksonDecoder(objectMapper);
}

@Bean
public Encoder encoder(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new JacksonEncoder(objectMapper);
}
```

Maybe you also need this additional dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This helped! I also had to define an ObjectMapper bean in my use case (Spring Batch job, no Spring Boot).